# db.sqlite3 cannot be ignored in git

Tags: git

I have add `*.sqlite3` to my `.gitignore_global` file:

[image]

When I run `git status` in my terminal there still have `db.sqlite3` listed as modified:

[image]

How can I ignore my SQLite file?

Comment: From your screenshot it doesn't actually look like you've added that entry to the ignore file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see three issues here:

1. **`.gitignore_global` isn't a standard Git ignore file.** If you haven't told Git about it it will have no effect. Something like `git config --global core.excludesfile <file>` can be used to add a global ignore file.
2. **Your screenshot actually doesn't show `*.sqlite3` in your ignore file.** You'll have to add that, or a pattern like it.
3. Finally, and most importantly, **Git's ignore system doesn't prevent tracked files from being modified. It only prevents files from being tracked in the first place.** Your screenshot shows `db.sqlite3` as being *modified*, not new.

   You can tell Git to stop tracking the file with `git rm --cached db.sqlite3`, then commit. This will leave the file in place, but remove it from the repository. Once that's done, and the previous two issues have been dealt with, your file should be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this command, and it did ignore changes in `db.sqlite3`:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged db.sqlite3
```

Comment: '[Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism. It is "I know my filesystem operations are slow. I'll promise Git that I won't change these paths by making them with that bit… Especially, it is *not* a promise by Git that Git will always consider these paths are unmodified—if Git can determine a path that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path *has been* modified (…`git commit -a` is free to commit that change).](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqy4z5go1y.fsf@gitster.dls.corp.google.com/)'

Comment: Sorry it worked for me perfectly, and it's well ignored in all commits

Comment: It might _look like_ it worked for you perfectly. That's one of the reasons it's such a bad idea. It seems like it's doing what you want, but it isn't. That quote is from the long-time maintainer of Git, and I strongly suggest you follow his advice. It's very likely that `db.sqlite3` shouldn't be in your repository _at all_. In that case it should be removed, e.g. with `git rm --cached db.sqlite3`, and that change should be committed.